How to compare sorting with lookup in mongodb 4.4?
I'm new to mongodb, I'm on version 4.4, no update possible.
I have a collection items with an attribute categories (array). I would like to "join" ($lookup) the collection categories to it - where each category has a sortOrder attribute - in order to compare if categories in items has a different sorting than in the collection categories.
My approach so far:
[
    {
        $addFields: {
            categoriesWithIndex: {
                $map: {
                    input: {$range: [0, {$size: "$categories" }]},
                    as: "index",
                    in: {
                        index: "$$index",
                        value: {$arrayElemAt: ["$categories", "$$index"]}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$categoriesWithIndex"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "categories",
            localField: "categoriesWithIndex.value",
            foreignField: "_id"
            as: "categoryDetails"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "categoriesWithIndex.sortOrder": {
                $arrayElemAt: ["$categoryDetails.sortOrder", 0]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            categories: {
                $push: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                        {
                            index: "$categoriesWithIndex.index",
                            sortOrder: "$categoriesWithIndex.sortOrder",
                            value: "$categoriesWithIndex.value"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
]

now the document looks like this:
_id: "1234"
categories: Array (3)

0: Object
index: 0
sortOrder: "2"
value: "catX"

1: Object
index: 1
sortOrder: "3"
value: "catY"

2: Object
index: 2
sortOrder: "1"
value: "catZ"

now it feels like I'm almost there, but I'm not sure how to continue. Unfortunately I don't have $sortArray...
could you please point me to the right direction?

i created a playground for your data https://mongoplayground.net/p/EbLhf8rZtno. do you want a boolean result?

I'm not sure what would be a best practice in mongodb, but I could imagine to concat categories as they are in items, and than sort them based on sortOrder and concat again and then compare if the two strings are identical... So yeah, a boolen would be great if this isapproximately what you mean :)

https://mongoplayground.net/p/U-G5d_Mk9bN  not sure if this is logically correct tho, im returning true if the categories array in items has ascending sorting order

thank you, that should be fine, I'm checking the db with it right away.

looks good! thank you!

let me know if you want me to post an answer

yes please post as answer

after the final grouping stage you can check if the sortOrder is in ascending order. If it is it means that items collection obey the sort order. If they are not in order means that items collection doesn't obey the sort order.
To check this you can try a $reduce pipeline stage. Start with true and check if sortOrder value of n+1 > n. Combining with $and you will get false if this condition is failed at least once.
you can add this as the last stage in your aggregation pipeline
{
  $addFields: {
    isSortOrderIncreasing: {
      $reduce: {
        input: { $range: [1, { $size: "$categories" }] },
        initialValue: true,
        in: {
          $and: [
            "$$value",
            {
              $gt: [
                { $arrayElemAt: ["$categories.sortOrder", "$$this"] },
                { $arrayElemAt: ["$categories.sortOrder", { $subtract: ["$$this", 1] }] }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

playground
